# PyPy slower than Cpython using tornado

Tags: python, jmeter, cpython, pypy

I have an account service for testing pypy and cpython using jmeter:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import uuid

class Account(object):
    def init(self):
        self.accounts = {}

    def create_account(self, name):
        account_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
        self.accounts[account_id] = name
        return account_id

account_service = Account()

class AccountHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, name):
        account_id = account_service.create_account(name)
        self.write({"accountId": account_id})
        print(account_id)

def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/create_account/(.*)", AccountHandler),
    ])

if name == "main":
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

Jmeter results(threads - 100, loop count - 100):
**Pypy: avg. ms - 78
Cpython: avg. ms - 6**
Looks like cpython works faster than pypy.
So, can someone explain, why is that?

I expect that pypy is faster than cpython.

Comment: What OS? What version of PyPy, tornado? I am not familiar with jemeter: what are the command line options you used to run it?